# Slide divs up/down depending on the radio selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched in several similar threads, but I do something wrong and it seems to not work.

I have this HTML structure:

```html
<div id="form" class="inquiry-section">
  <div class="inner">
  
    <div class="inner-form-col">
      <div class="inner-form"><input type="radio"><span>some label</span></div>
      <div class="inner-ab">
        <div class="inner-straight-ab">some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="inner-form-col">
      <div class="inner-form"><input type="radio"><span>some label</span></div>
      <div class="inner-ab">
        <div class="inner-gshape-ab">some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="inner-form-col">
      <div class="inner-form"><input type="radio"><span>some label</span></div>
      <div class="inner-ab">
        <div class="inner-pshape-ab">some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="inner-form-col">
      <div class="inner-form"><input type="radio"><span>some label</span></div>
      <div class="inner-ab">
        <div class="inner-isle-ab">some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is after clicking an *input* in **.inner-form** to .slideDown() the **.inner-ab** in the same **.inner-form-col** and to .slideUp() all the **.inner-ab** in the other columns. I made it work with .show() / .hide() or switching a class but as I need height: auto, I cannot achieve animation AND re-flowing the content below.

Comment: What do you mean height:auto?

Comment: I cannot make CSS transition from 0% to auto with switching a class.

Answer (score 0):

Have You try jQuery Easing Plugin

http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Comment: I don't think this is really what I need

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to make it work by using this, but I'm not 100% sure why it does:

```js
$('.inner-form-col').each(function() {
  var $dropdown = $(this);

  $(".inner-form input", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
    $div = $(".inner-ab", $dropdown);
    $div.slideDown();
    $(".inner-ab").not($div).slideUp();
  });

});
```